# System hang, out of ResAvail Pages in WinDbg

Tags: debugging, memory-management, memory-leaks, windbg

Been sleuthing a server hang issue for a couple months now. Every 2-2.5 weeks, a client's server grinds to a halt or bluescreens. It is a 2008 R2 VM (ESXi 5.5U2), with 25GB of RAM and several TB of hard disk space. Using vSphere to connect to the console during the issue, was able to move around a bit (slowly). The system couldnt open a notepad, cmd or even task manager reliably. Would give an error about not enough memory, or not enough storage.

Event Viewer was fairly helpful, pointing out the issue:
Event ID 14: Out of Kernel Memory
Event ID: 2019: Server Unable to allocate from the system nonpaged pool because the pool was empty

Awesome - problem solved, memory leak! But no...
Dove into all the usual tools / checks:
Available RAM was hovering around 20GB...
Available Pool and NonPaged pool were fine...
Commits looked good vs. the limits...
Handle counts we up there but well within normal ranges...
PoolMon showed nothing out of the ordinary except for a high PROC tag usage...
Ran a constant Perfmon to watch paged pool and non-paged pool and log to disk right up until a crash/hang - values were nowhere near limits...

Whats going on?

Then went to collecting crashdumps. Minidumps would fault different modules each time, and mostly bizzare, random ones (Video Memory, DirectX, etc).

Finally, this last time - I suspended the VM, flushing all 25GB of RAM to disk. Pulled the .vmss file and ran through the vmss2core utility and generated a full memory.dmp. Pulled the file into WinDBG and began fumbling around...

Stated that the faulting module was intelppm - which I know is a red herring because this is the driver that is last used to suspend the VM. And, with no pool available, different processes will choke and crash anyway.

So I ran the !vm like a good WinDbg n00b and after letting it grind away for a good 3 minutes, ctrl-break'd it and got this:

0: kd> !vm

> *** Virtual Memory Usage ***  Physical Memory:        6291342 (   25165368 Kb)    Page File: \??\C:\pagefile.sys    Current:  25165368 Kb 
>   Free Space:  25078668 Kb    Minimum:  25165368 Kb  Maximum:
>   75496104 Kb   Available Pages:        4686357 (   18745428 Kb)
>     **ResAvail Pages:               1 (          4 Kb)**
>
> ---

```
********** Running out of physical memory **********

Locked IO Pages:              0 (          0 Kb)
Free System PTEs:      33525293 (  134101172 Kb)

******* 1 system PTE allocations have failed ******


******* 159 system cache map requests have failed ******

Modified Pages:            6364 (      25456 Kb)
Modified PF Pages:         6364 (      25456 Kb)
Modified No Write Pages:      0 (          0 Kb)
NonPagedPool Usage:      105059 (     420236 Kb)
NonPagedPool Max:       4702718 (   18810872 Kb)
PagedPool 0 Usage:        32272 (     129088 Kb)
PagedPool 1 Usage:        20547 (      82188 Kb)
PagedPool 2 Usage:        18368 (      73472 Kb)
PagedPool 3 Usage:        18267 (      73068 Kb)
PagedPool 4 Usage:        18222 (      72888 Kb)
PagedPool Usage:         107676 (     430704 Kb)
PagedPool Maximum:     33554432 (  134217728 Kb)

********** 489 pool allocations have failed **********

Session Commit:            4738 (      18952 Kb)
Shared Commit:             9068 (      36272 Kb)
Special Pool:                 0 (          0 Kb)
Shared Process:         1003664 (    4014656 Kb)
Pages For MDLs:              77 (        308 Kb)
Pages For AWE:                0 (          0 Kb)
NonPagedPool Commit:          0 (          0 Kb)
PagedPool Commit:        107736 (     430944 Kb)
Driver Commit:             3385 (      13540 Kb)
Boot Commit:                  0 (          0 Kb)
System PageTables:            0 (          0 Kb)
VAD/PageTable Bitmaps:     3081 (      12324 Kb)
ProcessLockedFilePages:       0 (          0 Kb)
Pagefile Hash Pages:          0 (          0 Kb)
```

How in the world can I be 'running out of physical memory' with 25GB of RAM!? In hindsight (knowing what I've since Googled now) - I should have picked right up on the 'ResAvail Pages = 1'... But more on that in a moment...

Being the WinDBG n00b that I am, I ran the obligatory !process 0 0 command. The output scrolled on for a good 5 minutes! What?? How are all these processes active in RAM? I didn't see them in Process Explorer? Or reflected in high handle counts? After some Notepad++ magic on the resultant output... I had over 174631 instances of benign images such as cmd.exe, net.exe, findstr.exe, sc.exe... 
I grabbed the Process ID for a bunch of these, and traced their ParentCid with the !process command to quickly realize these were ALL leading back to the system monitoring agent installed on the server.

So... problem solved? Patch / Update / Remove the system monitoring software and call it a day, right?

Well, finally the true questions (and I appreciate your reading this far...): What the blazes are ResAvail Pages?? Why did this server have so little of them left, but had GBs and GBs of RAM, Pool and Commit percentages left showing in all available resource managers?

I found a great article that I *think* is probably exactly what is going on:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2013/09/04/resavail-pages-and-working-sets.aspx

But this is seriously the ONLY article on the Internets that I can find that gives any sort of reasonable explanation as to what ResAvail Pages are.

Is this issue seriously just the sum-total of all these unreleased processes minimal 20K working sets hanging out in memory, causing it to hit a proverbial ceiling and the kernel just refusing the allocate more memory, despite there is plenty available?

Should I be checking something else in WinDbg? Can I see a 'sum of all processes working sets' or whatever type of memory/object/construct it is that causes this ResAvail Pool to decrement? Why is this so mysterious? How could one ever hope to see this value creeping towards zero in Windows without a crash dump?

It just would be great to know more about this strange anomaly, any experts who could shed some more light on this ResAvail mystery will have my deepest gratitude. Please let me know if you'd like something run against the memory.dmp in WinDBG and I'd be happy to post the sanitized output here.

Thank you!

Comment: Nice work! `!process` shows all processes, not just those active in RAM. I wonder if most, if not all, of those instances of cmd.exe, etc. are zombie processes (meaning they have exited but there is still one or more handles referencing them). A process with zero threads is a zombie. Can you run `!process 0 2` and see if you see the string "No active threads" in the output anywhere? Also, how many handles did your original `!process 0 0` show for the agent monitoring process? My theory is that it is leaking process handles if it's the parent of a lot of zombies.

Answer (score 3):

since it appears you have the problem solved and the link you posted providing a very good explanation of the behaviour i assume your only query that remains is how you could get that data from a running system 
if so and if you could run livekd or can connect a kd to the server you can query the resvail pages using

```
C:\Users\XX>livekd  "-c \"? poi(nt!MmResidentAvailablePages)\";q" | grep -i eval
Evaluate expression: 459911 = 00070487
n
```

.

```
kd> .printf "%d gb of memeory would be used if all the %d process had its minimum\n",
 0n174631 * 0n200 / 0n1000000 , 0n174631
34 gb of memeory would be used if all the 174631 process had its minimum
```

[msdn link showing various memory limits including paged and non paged pool limits for various platforms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

a simple createprocess that didn't Close handles will occupy 20k and will linger around 
as an example

if you compile and run this code you can see a leaked 20k cmd.exe in `kd  using either !process 0 0 cmd.exe or !vm`

```
taskmgr / tasklist / wmic process none will show the process
```

rammap from sysinternals will show the 20 k pagetable entry in process tab

hold the enter key to create as many lingering cmd.exe as needed to experiment

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void main( void ) {
    STARTUPINFO si; PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    char binary[] = {"c:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe"};
    char arg2bin[] = {"/c"};    
    redo:
    memset(&si,0,sizeof(si)); memset(&pi,0,sizeof(pi));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    if((! CreateProcess(binary,arg2bin,NULL,NULL,FALSE,0,NULL,NULL,&si,&pi))) {
        printf( "CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError() );
        return;
    }
    WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );
    if(getchar() != 'N') { goto redo; };
}
```

there are 982 memory hugging cmd.exes that is  ignored by taskmgr / tasklist /wmic process / procexp by sysinternals  etc

livekd or real kd connection using !process or !vm only can show the 20k eating corpses (look for raymond's old_new_thing zombies article to get the drift about corpse)

sysinternals rammap can show the 20 k pagetable in the process tab

tasklist | grep -ic cmd
2

wmic process get name /format:list | grep -c cmd
2

livekd "-c \"!process 0 0 cmd.exe\";q" | grep -ic cmd
n
982

the ResAvailpages getting decreased on accumalation of corpse cmd.exes

```
livekd  "-c \"? poi(nt!MmResidentAvailablePages)\";q"  | grep -i eval
Evaluate expression: 455943 = 0006f507
y
Evaluate expression: 455166 = 0006f1fe
y
Evaluate expression: 455166 = 0006f1fe
y
Evaluate expression: 455037 = 0006f17d
y
Evaluate expression: 455102 = 0006f1be
y
Evaluate expression: 455102 = 0006f1be
y
Evaluate expression: 451086 = 0006e20e
y
Evaluate expression: 451638 = 0006e436
y

livekd  "-c \"? poi(nt!MmResidentAvailablePages)\";q"  | grep -i eval

livekd  "-c \"? poi(nt!MmResidentAvailablePages)\";q"  | grep -i eval
Evaluate expression: 449056 = 0006da20
y
Evaluate expression: 435712 = 0006a600
```